# Sending email as a job on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, jobs, sidekiq

I created a mailer to send an email to my client. As of right now I'm still testing it, but I couldn't make it to work. I've read Redis, Sidekiq, rails_mailer and still nothing. I can see that the mail is in the queue of Sidekiq UI but I can't receive the email.

Here's the flow of my code.

1. User will check the text box on the view if they wanted to send an email to a client.
2. A method will be triggered on the controller. Here's my code.

```
      def send_workorder_message
        if params.has_key?(:to_send_email)
          WorkorderMessage::WorkorderMessageJob.perform_in(10.seconds, @curr_user, params[:message])
        end
      endv
```

3. then a workorder job is created. Here's the code.

```
    
class WorkorderMessage::WorkorderMessageJob
  # include SuckerPunch::Job
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'mailers'

  def perform(user, message)
    Spree::WorkorderMailer.workorder_send_to_email(user, message).deliver_now


    # ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
    
    # end

  end
end
```

4. after that it will trigger the WorkorderMailer; here's the code:

```
    class WorkorderMailer < BaseMailer
    def workorder_send_to_email(to_user, message)
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do

        subject = "sample message mailer"

        @message = message
        @user = to_user

        mail(
          to: @user.email,
          # 'reply-to': Spree::Store.current.support_address,
          from: Spree::Store.current.support_address,
          subject: subject
        )
      end
    end
  end
```

When I use the preview mailer I can see the UI working fine.

Also I've noticed that on sidekiq view I see this `User` Obj. Is that normal?

[image]

Comment: I wonder if your `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` aren't configured correctly to deliver a transaction email. Can you share your `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` and omit any sensitive credentials?

Comment: You are specifying the job go to the `mailers` queue.  Are you starting Sidekiq with `-q mailers` so that it processes this queue?

Comment: When in doubt, don't configure things.  Let it use the default and everything will work out of the box.

Comment: MikePerham, MFrazier hello sir. actually, we have a working mailer. this is just addition at work. my senior is on vacation and its just me and him. but ill send some details on monday if i can get the codebase. thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Sidekiq documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices), the arguments you pass must be primitives that cleanly serialize to JSON, and not full Ruby objects, like the `user` you are passing here:

> Complex Ruby objects do not convert to JSON, by default it will
>   convert with to_s and look like `#<Quote:0x0000000006e57288>`. Even if
>   they did serialize correctly, what happens if your queue backs up and
>   that quote object changes in the meantime? Don't save state to
>   Sidekiq, save simple identifiers. Look up the objects once you
>   actually need them in your perform method.
>   The arguments you pass to perform_async must be composed of simple
>   JSON datatypes: **string, integer, float, boolean, null(nil), array and
>   hash**. This means you must not use ruby symbols as arguments. The
>   Sidekiq client API uses JSON.dump to send the data to Redis. The
>   Sidekiq server pulls that JSON data from Redis and uses JSON.load to
>   convert the data back into Ruby types to pass to your perform method.
>   Don't pass symbols, named parameters or complex Ruby objects (like
>   Date or Time!) as those will not survive the dump/load round trip
>   correctly.

I would suggest you change it to lookup the User by ID within the job, and only pass the ID instead of the entire user object.

```
# pass @curr_user.id instead of @curr_user
WorkorderMessage::WorkorderMessageJob.perform_in(10.seconds, @curr_user.id, params[:message])

# accept the ID instead of user here
def perform(user_id, message)

  # get the user object here
  user = User.find(user_id)

  # send the mail
  mail(
    to: user.email,
    #...
end
```

Comment: thank you for the response sir. I followed your advice. still got nothing. I also added a breakpoint on `def perform`  and `Spree::WorkorderMailer` it only hits the `def perform` method not the content of the method. thats why I think `workorder_send_to_email` method is not being invoked.

Comment: You might have trouble getting a worker to stop on a breakpoint, since it's typically working in another process. `puts "got here"` should work though, if you can see the output, or you could `Rails.logger.info("got here")`, and look in your log files.

Comment: tried it but no log showing. I also change the `deliver_later` to `deliver_now` nothing happened. Wierd thing is its showing on my sidekiq so technically it processing the job but I couldn't receive any emails.